# VB.NET input collected SQL result data into ASP.NET table

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

If you have collected some SQL data results using an `ExecuteReader()` command in VB.Net, what is the best of method of taking this data and displaying it in a table on a webpage?

Doing some experimenting, there seems to be numerous ways to achieve the results however I'm wondering: what is the best way of displaying the information?

I'm creating a standard table with four columns, I don't want the table to display more than thirty results.

Comment: This is not Classic ASP.

Comment: Yes ASP.net, my apologies.

Comment: As you say, there are many ways to do it.  I think it depends on your priorities; i.e. code readability, performance, reliability or ease of maintenance.  I'm sure one particular method will reasonably satisfy all of these criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Gridview and bind the its datasource to your datatable you fetched with the ExecuteReader command you mention. Also, in the Gridview properties set Allowpaging = true and Pagesize = 30.